# In TSQL How do I build a temp table with dynamic columns (or rows) based on row values from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot, dynamic-tables

What is the best way to build a temp tables with dynamic rows or columns - correspond to the row values of another query.

For example my query (this could change based on the user determination at any given moment)

```
SELECT ID, Description 
FROM TableX 
WHERE coded_value = 149 AND year = @year
```

will currently return values that appear as follows

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | In Person |
| 2 | Hybrid |
| 3 | Virtual |

I would select the `Description` field from this table and want those values to appear as columns in another table.

Here is how my code is built

The other table is built as follows

```
CREATE TABLE #final_table 
(
    [Year] varchar(5), 
    month_name varchar(25), 
    [month] int, 
    Requested int, 
    Num_Requested int, 
    Booked int,  
    Num_Booked int,  
    Cancelled int, 
    Num_Cancelled int, 
    category, varchar(10)
)

;WITH months ([monthDate], [month]) AS
(
    SELECT CAST(@Year + '-01-01' AS date), 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, [monthDate]), [month] + 1
    FROM months
    WHERE DATEADD(month, 1, [monthDate]) <= CASE WHEN @Year = YEAR(getdate()) THEN CAST(GETDATE() AS date) ELSE CAST(@Year + '-12-31' AS date) END
)
INSERT INTO #final_table (year, month_name, month)
    SELECT
        CONCAT('fy', SUBSTRING(CAST(Year AS varchar), 3, 2)) AS year, 
        DATENAME(month, [monthDate]) [monthDate], 
        [month] 
    FROM
        months
```

This query returns the following: a row for each month and year (as a parameter the user provided `@year`).

My output currently looks like this

| MonthName | MonthID | Requested | Other Columns Etc | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 1 | NULL | ... |  |
| February | 2 | NULL | ... |  |
| March | 3 | NULL | ... |  |
| April | 4 | NULL | ... |  |

What I want the output to look like

| A header | Another header | Requested | Other Columns | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 1 | NULL | ... | In - Person |
| January | 1 | NULL | ... | Hybrid |
| January | 1 | NULL | ... | Virtual |
| February | 2 | NULL | ... | In - Person |
| February | 2 | NULL | ... | Hybrid |
| February | 2 | NULL | ... | Virtual |

and so on

now alternatively I don't object to something like this either

| MonthName | MonthID | Requested In - Person | Requested Hybrid | Requested Virtual | Other Columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 1 | NULL | ... |  |  |
| February | 2 | NULL | ... |  |  |
| March | 3 | NULL | ... |  |  |
| April | 4 | NULL | ... |  |  |

Comment: I have read this several times and I can't for the life of me understand what you are trying to do here. What would really help is a sample table, data for that table, and the desired output based on that table.

Comment: If you look at a `SELECT .... INTO .... FROM ....` command, it may help - it basically creates a table containing the results of the query

Comment: @SeanLange I am trying to take the result set from a query (X rows) and turn those either into columns or row values. I have statistics but they need to be separated based on these X rows. I need to find out how many were requested/cancelled by type. The type changes so I would like to do it dynamically and not hard code them?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan I can't tell if you are trying to be rude or are serious? Select into got it. How do I do it dynamically is where i'm stuck!

Comment: What do you mean by do it dynamically? There is some detail here that is very clear to you but others are not getting it. Dynamically based on what?

Comment: Well when you want to add columns dynamically to your temp table based on user's choice, you need some workaround, , you might get some enlightenment on the same here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216250/create-temporary-table-with-dynamic-number-of-columns

Comment: @SeanLange dynamically from another query. If the query returns values XYZ then we will add a single column XYZ, but if the query returns three rows, with values A, B and C then we will add three columns, one called A one called B and one called C

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create temporary table with dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216250/create-temporary-table-with-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: In what way does using select into not accomplish this very task?

Comment: @GSM it may, I will review thank you

Comment: @SeanLange select what exactly, If i make the columns dynamic then I need to repeat them for each of the existing categories I have, if I make the rows dynamic I need to repeat them into each of the existing rows I have (per month). I'm not sure what i'm selecting

Comment: We are going around in circles here. You have a query right? Use that query to select into whatever new table you want. But I have a feeling that you just aren't sharing the whole picture of what you want to accomplish. How does months play into this? There is some level of details just totally lost in your explanation.

Comment: @SeanLange user requested data (by year) by month. For each month I need to total requested, cancelled and booked seats. For each of these fields there could be a category - they can be cancelled Virtual seats vs cancelled Hybrid seats, etc. Right now they have determined its three types of categories, but they could add or remove categories at any point -  those categories live in a a table. I want to make this report dynamic - whatever totals we are looking at and the corresponding categories (which could be changed any day) so hard coding isn't ideal

Comment: What would really help is to provide sample data and table structures. You see the whole direction you have steered this question is away from the solution. My guess is all you really need is a cross join to the categories table. But I am guessing against data structures and output based on a vague description.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR, without you putting more specifics into the question, I can't really build a dynamic `SELECT` and `WHERE` clause for you - without knowing the structure of your data there's not much I can suggest beyond using the `INTO` keyword.